# conflicts with merge using meld tool

Tags: git, github, meld

I have this problem to fix the conflict

[image]

The [meld](/questions/tagged/meld) tool "doesn't let me commit" the change on the middle, and this are the new changes that I need to commit.

I type:

```
$ git checkout MyBranch
$ git merge master
```

and the inverse

```
$ git checkout MyBranch
$ git merge master
```

and I did not get yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved. The problem was caused because i started the meld incorrectly, then he "hadn't" permission to edit the file *local* and *remote*. After configures him correctly, i typed:

`$ git mergetool`

Then, it starts each conflict's file

To configures him, i typed:

`$ git config --global mergetool.meld`